# add class after jquery's show and hide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, addclass

How do I slow down the add class event to occur gradually after the hide and show animation in Jquery?

The add class in this instance is read from the CSS file which essentially positions the paragraph. Every occurs sweetly but the add class is too abrupt and fast after the smooth animation.

The js file:

```
$(".grad").hide().show(3000, function() {
    $( this ).addClass("menubar");
});
```

Comment: Positions which paragraph? I can't work out what you're trying to do here without seeing some markup. Preferably make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

May be below code useful, without any test I wrote your answer

```
$(".grad").hide().show(3000, function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $( this ).addClass("menubar"); }, 3000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out myself. switchClass did not accomplish the task that well.
the addClass pointing to class:menubar in css positions the paragraph.

Solution: I renamed grad to menubar in the js file as well as the html file, the same as the class I wanted to introduce after show and hide and shortened everything. In this manner menubar loads gradually from the js as well as from css and animates not only the show and hide but also the css attributes; very cool.

```
$(".menubar").hide().show(3000);
```